# Function to find two prime numbers that sum up to a given even number

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, primes

The Goldbach Conjecture asserts that any even number over 2 will be the sum of exactly two prime numbers.  I've created a function to find two prime numbers that add up to the number entered, but would like some help streamlining it and making it more robust.  One thing I would like to add is the ability to find all prime pairs that add up to the given number and append them as tuples to a list and return it.  I have a separate function that will find all prime numbers lower than or equal to a given number.

```
def goldbach_conj(number):
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = 0
    if not number % 2:
        prime_list = list_of_primes(number)
        while result != number:
            for i in range(len(prime_list)):
                x = prime_list[i]
                if result == number: break
                for j in range(len(prime_list)):
                    y = prime_list[j]
                    result = x + y
                    print("Adding {} and {}.".format(x, y))
                    print("Result is {}".format(result))
                    if result == number: break
    return x, y 




def is_prime(number):
    if number % 2:
        # equivalent to if number % 2 != 0 because if number is
        # divisible by 2 it will return 0, evaluating as 'False'.
        for num in range(3, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
            if number % num == 0:
               return False
        return True
    else:
        return False



def list_of_primes(number):
    prime_list = []
    for x in range(2, number + 1):
            if is_prime(x):
                prime_list.append(x)
    return prime_list



def main():
    while True:
        usr_in = eval(input("Please enter a positive number"
                            " greater than 1: "))
        if usr_in > 1: break
        else:
            print("Number not valid.")

    prime_list = goldbach_conj(usr_in)
    print(prime_list)
    # prime_list = list_of_primes(usr_in)
    # for x in prime_list:
    #     print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this:

```
for i in range(len(prime_list)):
    x = prime_list[i]
```

and then don't use `i` again. So this can just be `for x in prime_list:`. Similarly in the `j` loop.

Just below that, this test:

```
if result == number: break
```

It's usually preferred to put the `break` on a new line.

You test this condition twice in a row - to break out of the inner `for` loop at the bottom of it and then again here. Instead of repeating yourself like that, use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to write them as one loop:

```
import itertools as it    
...
for x, y in it.product(prime_list, repeat=2):
    ...
    if result == number:
        break
```

To save another level of nesting, you can reverse this condition at the top:

```
if not number % 2:
```

to:

```
if number % 2:
    return 0, 0

x, y = 0, 0
```

This emphasises that you don't do any work in that case. You might want to add a short comment about *why* you don't need to. From your title, it sounds like you might want to treat this as an error condition and do this:

```
if number % 2:
    raise ArgumentError("Expected an even number")
```

Then you can move your `return` inside the `for` loop, in place of the `break`. At that point, continuing the search to find all pairs is trivial: change the `return` to a `yield`, and your function will become a *generator* that will keep yielding every pair that works until it has exhausted the search space.

This outer loop:

```
while result != number:
```

looks unneeded and possibly buggy. If the conjecture is true, you will find a pair, return it, and this will not be tested again. If you find a counter-example disproving the conjecture, then this would just do the whole search again giving you an infinite loop instead of fame and fortune. If you change it to `yield` each pair instead of returning the first one, this will repeat the full sequence indefinitely unless the very last pair tested happens to work. I would just drop it.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

You are doing an \$O(n^2)\$ search over a sorted list, which very often implies an affirmative answer to the infamous "can we do better?" question. For this particular problem, you can get \$O(n)\$ performance by simultaneously scanning from the front and back of the list of primes:

```
def prime_sieve(n):
    # returns all primes smaller than n
    sieve = [True] * n
    sieve[:2] = [False, False]  # 0 and 1 are not primes
    primes = []
    for prime, is_prime in enumerate(sieve):
        if not is_prime:
            continue
        primes.append(prime)
        for not_prime in range(prime*prime, n, prime):
            sieve[not_prime] = False
    return primes

def sum_of_primes(value):
    primes = prime_sieve(value)
    lo = 0
    hi = len(primes) - 1
    while lo <= hi:
        prime_sum = primes[lo] + primes[hi]
        if prime_sum < value:
            lo += 1
        else:
            if prime_sum == value:
                yield primes[lo], primes[hi]
            hi -= 1
```

Notice that, since generating all primes below `n` [can be done in \$O(n \log \log n)\$ time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity), it is now the prime generation that dominates the total time, i.e. using this faster algorithm makes finding the pairs virtually free (when compared to finding the primes themselves).

A sample run:

```
>>> list(sum_of_primes(42))
[(5, 37), (11, 31), (13, 29), (19, 23)]
```